# How to prevent automatic download of a linked mp3 file

Tags: google-chrome, download, mp3

I am making a website using only HTML and CSS. I am trying to link to an online mp3 file (that I do not own) so that the mp3 plays in the browser. This simple code does what I want on Firefox and Safari:

```
    <a href="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/assets/sound/548271.mp3" >
```

However, instead of playing the mp3, Chrome automatically downloads the mp3 file to my computer. Is there some way I can alter my HTML code (not my browser preferences) to stop this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: Try using a form instead of a link, e.g, `<form action="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/assets/sound/548271.mp3" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Play Audio"/></form>`. Untested, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks much, but Chrome still downloaded the mp3 file :(

Comment: Ohh I think I misunderstood the question. If you want the browser to provide an audio player interface instead of downloading the file, then go with @Brad's answer. I thought you were having problem with Chrome automatically prefetching the file before the user clicks the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee that all the browsers will have a built-in in-frame player for the audio file.

The best thing to do in this case is to embed the audio player into a page with the audio element:

```
<audio src="https://example.com/some-sound.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Comment: I think you are right in that I will have to use the audio player. I had tried it initially but the default style doesn't look good on my page - this is an art project. So, I am learning to style it. More fun!

Comment: @nibor You can skip the default styling and implement your player in JavaScript, and then use any controls or styling you want on your page to control it.  `const a = new Audio('https://example.com/some-sound.mp3');  a.play();`  Just don't forget to call `.play()` on a user interaction, like a click event, or it may be blocked by the browser.

Comment: Brad! I had not used JavaScript before, but I learned enough to get this working. Now it runs like a charm. Thanks so much.

Comment: @nibor Awesome, glad you got it working!